# Export to Excel but filter certain rows

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, export-to-excel

I have a datagridview, called dgvSNEvents, that looks like the following:

[image]

This dgv is only a small sampling but what I need is to export this dgv without any of the rows that contain "No Data Found" where you see them above.  Here's the code I use to export everything including the unwanted rows. The export is done through Office Automation and I can produce a file just fine.

```
For iX = 0 To dgvSNEvents.Rows.Count - 1
    For iY = 0 To dgvSNEvents.Columns.Count - 1
        If dgvSNEvents.Rows(iX).Cells("Event Outcome").Value = "F" Then
        ' this will paint the background in red because the column named "Event Outcome" has an "F" for a value
                xlCells(iX + 2, iY + 1).interior.colorindex = 22
                xlCells(iX + 2, iY + 1).value = dgvSNEvents(iY, iX).Value
        Else
        ' there aren't any "F's" so just export the row
                xlCells(iX + 2, iY + 1).value = dgvSNEvents(iY, iX).Value
        End If
    Next
Next
```

I don't know if this is enough to go on so I will edit this as needed.

---

Here is my output after applying OSKM's code:

[image: Code change for output to Excel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need is an if statement to check the data and a seperate variable to determine the location on the exported spreadsheet such as:

```
Dim XlRow as Int32 = 0
For iX = 0 To dgvSNEvents.Rows.Count - 1
        'add ifstatement to skip column loop if cell entry is 'No Data Found'
        If dgvSNEvents.Rows(iX).Cells("Part Number").Value <> "No Data Found" Then 
            For iY = 0 To dgvSNEvents.Columns.Count - 1
                If dgvSNEvents.Rows(iX).Cells("Event Outcome").Value = "F" Then
                ' this will paint the background in red because the column named "Event Outcome" has an "F" for a value
                    xlCells(XlRow + 2, iY + 1).interior.colorindex = 22
                    xlCells(XlRow + 2, iY + 1).value = dgvSNEvents(iY, iX).Value
                Else
                ' there aren't any "F's" so just export the row
                    xlCells(XlRow + 2, iY + 1).value = dgvSNEvents(iY, iX).Value
                End If
            Next
            XlRow += 1
        End If
Next
```

Comment: I added an image to my original post after applying your code.  As this is being done through Office Automation I wonder if it would be possible to delete empty rows programmatically?  Or would that be a performance loss?

Comment: @ctmcklowe96 Sorry there was an error in my code - see update above!

Comment: That definitely worked.  I'm wondering though, is this the best approach, or should I be looking more at the solution that Neolisk provided?  If I understand his suggestion correctly then it would be exporting all at once, instead of row by row as I'm currently doing. I only ask because we'll have times where the dgv may contain 30,000+ rows and this may be a 'bit' slow.

Comment: @ctmcklowe96 I might be wrong but i believe to get any form of formatting on the excel you will have to use the cell by cell approach, if you discover a better way to do it please post it here as i would definitley be interested.

Comment: @ctmcklowe96: My suggestion would only help to increase maintainability of the code. If you want performance, consider exporting your data into a CSV file and then Excel should be able to open that.

Answer (score 0):

I would do export from a data table instead. Filter the rows using `Select()`, and put them into another data table. Export this new data table into Excel. The code will become much more simple to maintain.

**EDIT:** Or even export from an array of `DataRow()`, because that's what `Select()` would return. You will have some performance gain, by not having to create a data table. If you decide to have your `Select()` criteria dynamic, you can do that, and then doing an empty `Select()` returns everything AS IS, so it looks like all corner cases are covered for you.

Comment: I've not used the Select() before, could you provide a simple example or link to one?  More specifically one that would include a dgv as a datasource?

Comment: @ctmcklowe96: Assuming your `DataSource` is a `DataTable`, you could do something like `DirectCast(dgv.DataSource, DataTable)`, but it's better to store the original `DataTable` as a class level variable (before or after you assign it). Regarding usage of `Select()`, check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx).